# Solr Search and QueryParser

Tags: magento, solr, solrj

I have a mangeto installation with apache-solr (in linux environment)

When I am searching with a keyword, it shows unrelated products.

Later И figure out that solr is adding a query text and search with that also.

**Here is the example:**
Below is a part of my solr results xml,

```
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">bbb</str>
<str name="querystring">bbb</str>
<str name="parsedquery">text:PP text:bbb</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">text:PP text:bbb</str>
```

I search with the keyword "**bbb**". But in the parsedquery the solr has added an another query string as "**PP**".

So this is returning the products have "pp" in in description.

How I can prevent this automatically generation of a query text.

I hope you will clear my issue.

Comment: what is the query parser configured on the solr instance? You can check that from the solrconfig.xml and traces of that should be on the field definition in the schema.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's a dismax/edismax parser. Query passes the analysis chain as defined for the 'text' field type. Your 'PP' is somehow related to 'bbb', therefore the query is expanded. E.g. it can be a stemmed variation, or a synonym etc.
Check your schema.xml as D_K suggested.